# How to send event messages from AsynTask (best practice)?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have typical `AsyncTask` that I want to properly decouple from my `Activity` classes and UI logic.
I think of doing it this way:

1. Make listener interface

   ```
   public interface MyTaskListener {   
       void onTaskProgress(...);   
       void onTaskDone(...);
   }
   ```
2. Make my `Activity` implement `MyTaskListener` and pass `this` reference on task creation.
3. Call listener methods in`onPreExecute()`, `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()`.

But may be I'm reinvetning the wheel and Android framework has something better already implemented? I think of something like `EventBus` pattern where all interested parties can register for particular event types that I can fire from my `AsyncTask`.

Comment: your approach seems okay to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface is most clean way of doing this, because your task class is 'sealed', knows nothing about surrounding environment (does not access any stuff from outer class which quite tempting when you use inner classes) and communicates back with generic channel.